Is there an appreciable difference in the effectiveness of engine braking depending on the displacement of the engine?
You're riding a 1.0 litre engine at 50 kph (30 mph) in third gear in a manual-transmission car. You remove your foot from the gas pedal, without declutching. You measure how many seconds and how many meters (or feet) it takes you until your speed drops — passively from the "engine brakes" — to 40 kph.
You repeat exactly the same experiment in the same car with a 2.0 litre engine.
Is there an appreciable difference in the effectiveness of engine braking depending on the displacement of the engine?
This question arose from a comparison between "fixie" riding and manual-transmission car driving over at bicycles.SE.

Short answer: yes, longer answer: also yes but it's not the only factor a good chunk of what we think of as engine braking is caused but vacuum draw on the intake stroke of the engine when the throttle is closed (this is why diesels don't get the same engine braking as petrols unless there's some clever trickery to mimic it) and the larger the displacement of the engine the bigger the volume of the cylinders and the bigger this vacuum effect is. This volume is not the only factor at play though, there's the compression ratio of the engine to consider, the flywheel, the transmission losses, rolling resistance of the tires, and of course aerodynamic drag too. So it's not as simple as doubling the displacement giving you twice the same deceleration but appreciable? Sure thing, if the displacement difference is big enough you'll probably be able to notice it between two otherwise very similar cars.

Engine braking on diesel engines is done via a Jacob's Brake or Jake Brake (if so equipped). Very effective, but very loud. It works very differently from what we consider engine braking in a gasoline engine.

Also, a car with a 1-litre engine is quite likely to be lighter than one with a 2-litre engine. The heavier car has more momentum. On a motorcyle, the engine braking is even better, because of its lighter weight and greater drag, so unless you take-it-to-the-limit there is rarely any need to apply the brakes except when stopping or unless something unexpected happens.

You answered "yes", but I hadn't suggested (in the question) which side might have stronger brakes. To be clear, you're arguing that it's the 2.0 engine that will provide the stronger brakes.

@Sam7919 Yeah, the "yes" is by way of a direct answer to the "is there an appreciable difference" aspect. I explained about the whole effect of the cylinder volume to show what that effect would be, i.e. that larger displacement petrol engine = larger engine braking effect
